# How to translate simple MongoDB query with $not operator from shell to PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm struggling with converting a simple MongoDB query into PHP. Let's say I have the following collection:

```
{ "_id": 1, "text" : "I agree with you." }  
{ "_id : 2, "text" : "They agreed with him." }  
{ "_id : 3, "text" : "They wrote an agreement." }
```

In the shell, if I enter:

```
db.collection.find({ text: {$not: /\bagreed\b/i}})
```

it nicely excludes the item with _id:2, as follows:

```
{ "_id": 1, "text" : "I agree with you." }  
{ "_id : 3, "text" : "They wrote an agreement." }
```

How do I convert this simple query into an equivalent query in PHP? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$collection->find(array('text' => array('$not' => new \MongoRegex("/\bagreed\b/i"))));`

Comment: Colin, thank you for your prompt reply. That worked very nicely. Placing the "\" in front of MongoRegex is what did the trick. Thanks again.